# A simple question in calculus (equivalence of limits).

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I want to prove the next equivalence:
[image]

where D-lim, is $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty , \ n \notin M \subset \mathbb{N}}$.

The easy part, mainly $\Rightarrow$ I did I think good.

I am having diffuclty with proving the other side, i.e, $\Leftarrow$.

I want to do some telescoping sums here, but I keep failing.

We know that $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} |a_k -a |}{n+1} \geq \min_{k}{|a_k-a|}$, but I don't see this as very helping to me.

I see now that there might be a typo in the scan, cause if it's as written with |a_n-a| and not |a_k-a|, then trivialer than I last thought.

So how to show the other side of this.

PS
I forgot to mention, that $a_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Comment: So $M$ is arbitrary set?

Comment: It's a subset of the natural numbers.

Comment: I should also add that this exercise appears in Krengel's book called "ergodic theorems" on page 96.

Answer (score 0):

For the backward, what you need to show that there is a convergent subsequence, since if that's true, you can set $M$ be the non-convergent index.

It suffices to show the case when $a=0$.

And it suffices to show $\forall \epsilon>0,\forall N\in \mathbb{N},\exists n>N$, s.t.,$|a_n|<\epsilon$.

Suppose not, $\exists \epsilon_0>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N},\forall n>N$, s.t.,$|a_n|\geq\epsilon_0$. Set $M=\sum_{i=0}^N |a_i|$

Then $\forall n>N+1, \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i|}{n}=\frac{M+\sum_{i=N+1}^{n-1} |a_i|}{n}>\frac{M}{n}+\frac{(n-N-1)\epsilon_0}{n}\to \epsilon_0>0$

We get a contradiction.

Comment: Your last inequality should actually be: $$> M/n + \epsilon_0(n-1-N)/n$$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist You are right. I will edit it. Thanks!